# Incorrect rates from API and UPS website ActiveShipping gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, shopify

I got incorrect rates using the UPS service.
The issue is that I got different rates received from the gem and from the website
I got:
Website: 418.22USD for UPS Next Day Air
ActiveShipping: 485.62 for UPS Next Day Air

From: 59101
To: 59452
Wight: 96 lbs
Packages 50lbs + 46lbs

Rates from ActiveShipping:

```
=> {"UPS Second Day Air"=>25350, "UPS Next Day Air"=>48562}
```

Rates on web
[image]

I'm missing some params that can be different on web that on ActiveShipping?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As of 2.2 (untagged) UPS will no longer be a supported carrier in the active shipping gem [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) so this might be causing issues for you